# React, how to tell a parent component that all child components have completed updating?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have a react application that takes in a fairly large chunk of orders (we can think of them as online orders from a store).   I then take those orders and sort them based on various criteria and display them within various categories ("Toys", "Home Goods", etc).

The end result is something like this:

Toys (2)

- Order for Truck
- Order for Doll

Home Goods (2)

- Mirror
- Flowers

Code wise it is as simple as a category component calling as many order components as it needs.

Category Component

- Order Component
- Order Component

Each order component also has a form with it so that the user can, if they want, update something about that order.

Because there are potentially many categories (maybe dozens) and potentially upwards of a thousand orders I don't render the actual orders until someone clicks and opens the category (otherwise react slows to a crawl trying to render everything).  In the actual orders I even went so far as to not render the form fields until they choose that specific order to update.   Both the rendering of the orders and of the form inside each order are controlled by some conditional rendering.

So performance is pretty acceptable at this point.

The catch is that there is still a delay when a user clicks to open a category with say 1000 orders, maybe about 3 to 4 seconds.

I'd like to indicate that there is some loading going on as soon as the user clicks so they don't get impatient go all click happy and mount and unmount until their browser blows up.  It would be something like:

-*click*-

Category Component  -spinner or something-

-*3 to 4 seconds pass*-

Category Component -no spinner-

- Order Component
- Order Component

I've done loading icons for waiting for API calls and such and that's fine, 
 but I'm not sure how to actually indicate that we're waiting for React to finish rendering lots of child components and tell the parent components to no longer display the spinner?

If this was just one parent component and one child component I'd pass a function from the parent to the child that updates a "hey i'm done" state in the parent to stop displaying the spinner.

However, if I pass the children each such a function that's 1000+ functions that 1000+ children are going to use to update one parent parent, that seems like a bad idea to have that state updated 1000+ times.

I thought about passing the children a function that adds something to an array in the parent.  It would be something like a "reporting in array", it doesn't matter what is in the array really, I would just check in the parent if the "reporting in array' has the same length as children... but that also felt wonky.

Is there a better / good way for a parent to be aware of its children's current state / if it completed rendering on the DOM, or if the children completed updating?

Longer term I have some plans for introducing pagination and some other efforts to cut back on the rendering of 1000+ orders in a category but for now customers "want" all orders open at once.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you looked into React Virtualized or similar? https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: `but that also felt wonky` - it feels a lightweight simple solution to me.

Comment: Mosh, it just seems like there must be something "in react" that "should" be there that tells or I could use to tell a parent their children are updated or rendered, but googling left and right I find nothing like that... the "reporting in array" might be the route i end up going.